# How i can make a stl file from a set of points in Python?

Tags: python, 3d

I have a list of point [[x1, y1,z1], [x2, y2, z2] ... ]. These are all points of the figure. How i can make stl file? I tried to use this - [Create a .stl file from a collection of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066405/create-a-stl-file-from-a-collection-of-points), but i didn't have success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Visit here for generating stl file using similar approach that might work: https://micronote.tech/2020/12/Generating-STL-Models-with-Python/